# Linked list node creation

Tags: c, linked-list

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int value;
    struct node* next;
} node_t;

void push (node_t *root, int value) {
    node_t* current = root;

    if(current == NULL) {
        current = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
        current->value = value;
        current->next = NULL;
    }
    else {
        while(current->next != NULL)
            current = current->next;

        current = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
        current->value = value;
        current->next = NULL;
    }
}

void print (node_t* root) {
    node_t* current = root;
    while(current != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", current->value);
        current = current->next;
    }   
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main(void) {
    node_t* root = NULL;
    push(root, 5);
    push(root, 10);
    push(root, 15);
    print(root);

    return 0;
}
```

Why this code is not working?

I am trying to make a linked list without initialization in `main`. Is it possible?

I want it to take the non-initialized `root` node from `main` and initialize it in the function `push()` so it is the first node in linked list.

I do not want to do this:

```
int main() {
    node_t* root = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    root->value = 0;
    root->next = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Debugger.................

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Tell us what is not working.

Comment: can you add your **structure definition** to your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void push (node_t *root, int value)
```

The `root` node is never returned to the caller. You either need to accept the the `node_t*` for the `root` node as a pointer, hence `node_t**` to be able to allocation the root in its original location, or return the newly allocated `current` node.

```
node_t * push (node_t *root, int value)
```

Then;

```
node_t * push (node_t *root, int value) {
    node_t* current = root;
    /*...*/
    return current;
}
```

Given the update code; the above is still applicable, but you demo sample in main would need modification. The `node_t**` option would be better.

Your `push()` function has two issues; accepting the `node_t**` and setting the `root` node when it is created; and correctly inserting the new node when the `root` is already created;

```
// accept the root as node_t**
void push (node_t **root, int value) {
    node_t* current = *root; // get the root node

    if (current == NULL) {
        current = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
        current->value = value;
        current->next = NULL;
        *root = current; // set the root node
    }
    else {
        while (current->next != NULL) {
            current = current->next;
        }

        // create the new node in the place of the "next" node
        current->next = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
        current->next->value = value;
        current->next->next = NULL;
    }
}
```

---

A full listing;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int value;
    struct node* next;
} node_t;

void push (node_t **root, int value) {
    node_t* current = *root;

    if (current == NULL) {
        current = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
        current->value = value;
        current->next = NULL;
        *root = current;
    }
    else {
        while (current->next != NULL) {
            current = current->next;
        }

        current->next = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
        current->next->value = value;
        current->next->next = NULL;
    }
}

void print (node_t* root) {
    node_t* current = root;
    while(current != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", current->value);
        current = current->next;
    }   
}

int main(void) {
    node_t* root = NULL;
    push(&root, 5); // note the additional &
    push(&root, 10);
    push(&root, 15);
    print(root);

    return 0;
}
```

*Note*; this was compiled with `-std=c11` language level compatibility.

Comment: or better make root a `node_t *root` a global variable

Comment: double pointers are  sometimes mind blowing for me , thank you